# Remove/Fill background color - React Native Animation

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Is this doable? [Check this link for example](http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/4681/).

I've been trying to make it work. This is my current code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animationValue: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

<Animated.View 
  style={{ flex: 0.15, backgroundColor: `rgba(0,0,0,${background}` }} 
  onPress={this.removeBackground}
>
    <Text style={[{ textAlign: 'right' }>{hometeam.result} - {awayteam.result}</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

The `background` is a variable that looks like this:

```
const background = this.state.animationValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, 1] 
});
```

What I want to happen is when you click on the animated view, I want the background color to fade. So I was trying to use rgba and change the alpha based on the background variable, which gave me an error.

This is my function to remove the background:

```
removeBackground = () => {
  this.state.animationValue.setValue(0);
  Animated.timing(this.state.animationValue, {
    toValue: 1, 
    duration: 2000,
  }).start();
}
```

Any clues how I could do this?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: An error that says that backgroundColor cannot take object as value: rgba(0,0,0,[object Object])

Comment: You can use `rgb backgroundColor` and modify the animation based on the `opacity` style